# get a push notification depending on geo location

Tags: objective-c

i wanna start to program an app where the user receives information when he/she enters a location. this is no problem when the app is running. what i want is, that the user receive a push notification when the app is not running. this notification should only appear when he/she enters that specific location.

so my question is:
is it possible to receive a push notifications if the phone enters a specific geo-area?
(the app is not running/phone is in the pocket)

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, take a look at this part of the documentation:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW10

EDIT: Actually it is not a push notification, it becomes more of a local notification where the system will wake your app up from sleep when you enter a certain geo-location. You can also run your application in the background tracking the device via gps at all times. But that approach is not recommended unless you really need it for some reason, for example to speak out directions.

Comment: Thank you, so i can start to program :)

Answer (score 0):

Urban Airship allows to send push notifications based on geoarea.
However, I think you'll better use Petar's solution, if you need to get notification that user get into area.